# Logical construction of the word "forget"

Tags: meaning, etymology

A small story behind the reason for this question.

In Russian, just as in English, many fundamental words are a combination of two basic ones. The verb *"forgot"* is *"zabil"* in Russian. It is formed by ***"za"*** - in this case most likely in the meaning of *"after"* - and ***"bil"*** - literally *"was"* or *"I am in the past"*. If you put them together, it forms a logical structure of *"after the way I was"*.

In English we have *"forget/forgot"*. As it happens in Russian, it is formed by *"for"* and *"get"* in different tenses. What meaning do these two words logically take (if any), to be righteously forming the word that logically means *"to lose something that was known"*?

Comment: http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=forget

Comment: I didn't know that "for" can take the form of "opposite to". Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OED shows that the second element is ultimately from the hypothetical Old German *getan*, having the sense ‘to hold, grasp’. The first element has the sense of missing or forfeiting something. The OED concludes:

> The etymological sense is thus ‘to miss or lose one's hold’; but the
>   physical application is not recorded in any Germanic language.